# Is there a limit to how many key presses VB.NET can register at once?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, keypress

So I'm currently designing my A-level computing project, and I need to know if VB.NET can register multiple keypresses at the same time, e.g F&J, and be able to treat them as separate keypresses. I may need anywhere up to 4 keypresses at once so if VB.NET can't do it, my program will be limited (though only slightly).

If this is possible, do i just treat it as if they weren't pressed at the same time and check for both keys individually, or is there a special way of detecting this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure VB has anything to do with, its your keyboard driver and hardware that are responsible for that. some gaming keyboards for example, can handle 10 key presses simultaneously , standard keyboards can handle like 3 to 5 tops.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. Your application will pickup all keys that are registered by the PC.
You will have to catch which keys are pressed in your application.

Comment: It is a property of the keyboard, called ["rollover"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)).   You can generally count only on 3 keys, cheap ones clunk out after that.  There isn't any way to find out, other than by trial and error, it does depend where the keys are located in the matrix.  Or by careful shopping.  The queue size has nothing to do with it.

Comment: thanks guys, this is helpful, 3 will be enough for my project and its nice to know i dont have to do anything more special than i was already doing to catch them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep track of the keys you have pressed, and released.

Create a new winforms project and add a Label. This should give you a good starting point.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private pressedKeys As New List(Of System.Windows.Forms.Keys)()

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
        If Not pressedKeys.Contains(e.KeyCode) Then pressedKeys.Add(e.KeyCode)
        printCurrentKeys()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
        If pressedKeys.Contains(e.KeyCode) Then pressedKeys.Remove(e.KeyCode)
        printCurrentKeys()
    End Sub

    Private Sub printCurrentKeys()
        If pressedKeys.Count > 0 Then
            Me.Label1.Text = pressedKeys.
                Select(Of String)(Function(k) Chr(k)).
                Aggregate(Function(s1, s2) s1 & ", " & s2)
        Else
            Me.Label1.Text = ""
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

[image]

(The above 8 keys made possible by my [anti-ghosting](https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx) keyboard, the [Sidewinder X4](https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/content/projects/SideWinderX4.aspx).)

Answer (score 1):

Supposedly you can check in the registry

```
Dim KeyboardDataQueueSize = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue(
            "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Kbdclass\Parameters", 
            "KeyboardDataQueueSize", Nothing)
```

https://www.google.com/search?q=keyboard+buffer+size